# Storing data in db through HTTP PUT

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-services, put

This is my HTTP PUT method. This code is not giving any exceptions but still not storing data in database can anyone please help. Model is my getter setters class.

```
[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage Addfood(int id,[FromBody] Model model)
{
    Food food = new Food();
    var userid = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID == id);
    if (userid == null)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "No Record Found");
    }

    food.UID = id;
    food.Name = model.Foodname;
    food.Price = model.Foodprice;
    food.Image = model.Foodimage;
    food.Date_Time = DateTime.Today;
    Category category = new Category();
    category.Name = model.Categoryname;
    db.Categories.Add(category);
    food.CatID = category.ID;
    db.Foods.Add(food);
    db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, food);
}
```

My Database tables.

```
 [dbo].[Food](
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Image] [image] NULL,
        [Price] [varchar](10) NULL,
        [CatID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [UID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Date/Time] [datetime] NULL,


[dbo].[Category](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,

[dbo].[User](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Phone] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [AID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Password] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Date/time] [datetime] NULL,
    [IsVerify] [bit] NULL,
    [ProfilePicture] [image] NULL,
```

I am calling from this url

```
http://localhost:11434/api/Food/52
```

When i am hitting this request through postman.these are the params which i am giving in postman.

```
{"Foodname":"Bir","Foodprice":"210","Categoryname":"H000"}
```

i am getting this code in postman but my database is not updating. Why this ID = 0 my id field is auto incremented.

```
{
    "ID": 0,
    "Name": "Bir",
    "Image": null,
    "Price": "210",
    "CatID": 0,
    "UID": 52,
    "Date_Time": "2018-12-05T00:00:00+05:00",
    "Category": null,
    "User": {
        "ID": 52,
        "Name": "h999",
        "Phone": 3332158086,
        "Email": "a.b.c@yahooooo.com",
        "AID": 36,
        "Password": "030021",
        "Date_time": "2018-12-05T03:26:13.82",
        "IsVerify": null,
        "ProfilePicture": null,
        "Address": null,
        "Flags": [],
        "Foods": [],
        "Order_Tracking": [],
        "Order_Tracking1": []
    },
    "FoodRecommendations": [],
    "Order_Tracking": [],
    "Ratings": []
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you aren't getting any exceptions? Not even warning? I can see you haven't used async/await in your method anywhere. Try adding an await to the SaveChangesAsync line and mark the method as async. Not sure if this will work but it's worth a shot. Also, you might want to check the debugger in the browser to see if there are any errors in the console.

Comment: @PrashantTiwari i am not getting any warning and yes i did tried await but thats not working

Comment: Your method is defined as synchronous, it is not awaitable because it does not return a `Task<T>` or `Task`. You should be calling `db.SaveChanges();` and **not** `db.SaveChangesAsync();`. Your current code might dispose of the `DbContext` before it finishes execution which is what could be happening if you are getting a `200` response.

Comment: What @Igor suggested is also one thing to try out.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage Addfood(int id,[FromBody] Model model)
{
    Food food = new Food();
    var userid = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID == id);
    if (userid == null)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "No Record Found");
    }

    food.UID = id;
    food.Name = model.Foodname;
    food.Price = model.Foodprice;
    food.Image = model.Foodimage;
    food.Date_Time = DateTime.Today;
    Category category = new Category();
    category.Name = model.Categoryname;

    food.Category = category;
    db.Foods.Add(food);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, food);
}
```

Since you are also creating a new category for new food, you need to use `food.Category=category` instead of `food.CatID` as it will not be populated until you call `SaveChanges` method

Comment: But i want category id in food table

Comment: @HanzalaIqbal101 Have you tried the suggested code? I believe it should insert a new category in Category table and also link it to the food using id.

Comment: Yes i tried you code but this is giving an exception on Savechages()

Comment: @HanzalaIqbal101 What is the exception?

Comment: An error oocured while updating the entities see the inner details

Comment: @HanzalaIqbal101 Put try catch around `db.SaveChages()` and debug code to check what is the error.